# Locale Switch not Affecting News Index Template

Tags: localization

So I have successfully set up two locales on my site, with a button to switch between, this works fine for all the sections that have the langauges set, but I cannot seem to get it to work for the news index template, my news feed. An individual entry will work fine, but the collated entries don’t. Is there a snippet I need to place at the top of the News index template to define what locale it should contain?

Comment: Is [this](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/46/125) the language switch you are using? Do you want to translate URLs and slugs?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This Google+ thread may help: https://plus.google.com/116942350387086245334/posts/TBtR3XwuZGx

Current options as per above thread:

- Create a *Single* for the News index template
- Create a *localized template* as per http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating-overview#template-localization

Comment: It’s a shame that something as standard as a blog needs a workaround like these. Thanks Andrea.

Comment: @simon it's not a workaround but simply the difference between entry pages, which get the Url from section url and slug settings, and unrelated pages as your index.html, that Craft doesn't know about.

Comment: Other then to make the index a *Single* section, I suggest to also consider designing a *Structure* section, with all your single pages and your channel index page becoming entries of that section (with individual entry types if needed). Then you can translate the slugs of all your pages with ease and your language switch works as it is.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to translate the sections URLs and the entries slugs then there's a very easy way to do a language switch. Just append [`craft.request.path()`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.request#path) to your localized base URL.

```
<a href="{{ 'http://craft.dev/' ~ craft.request.path() }}" class="nav-link{{ craft.locale == 'pt_BR' ? ' current' }}">BRA</a>
<a href="{{ 'http://craft.dev/de/'  ~ craft.request.path() }}" class="nav-link{{ craft.locale == 'de' ? ' current' }}">GER</a>
```