# Problems with Localized Site Navigation

Tags: localization, navigation

I`ve got a multilingual site (DE/EN) with a Structures section (pages) and one Single for the homepage.

In general.php I set up my localized site as described in the docs for a multi-environment config. German at the top level; English from en/ subfolder:

```
'domain.dev' => array(
    'siteUrl' => array(
        'de' => 'http://domain.dev/',
        'en' => 'http://domain.dev/en/',
    ),
),
```

Within my public html folder I copied .htaccess and index.php to en/ and added define('CRAFT_LOCALE', 'en'); to index.php

Navigating to **domain.dev** shows the german pages:

- Seite 1
- Seite 2
- Seite 3

Changing the URL manually to **domain.dev/en/** shows their right translations

- Page 1
- Page 2
- Page 3

and also their right links, e.g. http://domain.dev/en/page-1

BUT following the link to **domain.dev/en/page-1** the german content shows up again and the **navigation switches back to german**.

```
{% set pages = craft.entries.section('pages').level(1) %}
<nav>
    <ul>
        {% for page in pages %}
            <li>{{ page.getLink() }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Going to any other english page (e.g. domain.dev/en/page-2) doesn't show up the english content (a translatable field) at all but neither the german content. So I think there is something wrong with my localization setup. Any ideas? Thanks much!

---

#### UPDATE

I set up a new craft installation and also a Localized Site as described in the docs.
When defining the site URLs this way everything **works like a charm**:

```
return array(
    'siteUrl' => array(
        'de' => 'http://craft.dev/',
        'en' => 'http://craft.dev/en/',
    ),
);
```

in combination with my **multi-environment config** it **is not working**.

```
return array(
    'craft.dev' => array(
        'siteUrl' => array(
            'de' => 'http://craft.dev/',
            'en' => 'http://craft.dev/en/',
        ),
    ),
);
```

So I think my config is missing something to transmit the locale the right way?

Is there another way to set up a localized site with multi-environment config?

Comment: When you setup your second locale, did you set it up as generic "English", or something more specific like "English - United States" or "English - Great Britain"? Make sure that your locale code is actually `en`, and not `en_us` or `en_gb`. If it _is_ a country-specific code, then just change the code specified in your index.php file.

Comment: On a related note, yesterday I released a new [Language Link plugin](https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-languagelink), designed to make switching between languages a much easier process.

Comment: I set it up as generic English (en) and double checked the index.php. With the Language Link Plugin I had the same problems.. so I really think it is a configuration thing.

Comment: multi-environment config needs to have the _*_ key: `return array('*' => array(), 'craft.dev' => array(...));`

Comment: @MarionNewlevant You may want to submit that as a formal answer... I suspect that's the actual solution to the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A multi-environment config needs to have a `*` key. This might work:

```
return array(
  '*' => array(),
  'craft.dev' => array(
    'siteUrl' => array(
      'de' => 'http://craft.dev/',
       en' => 'http://craft.dev/en/',
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to specify the **locale** of your nav links... `craft.locale` is the current locale.

```html
{% set pages = craft.entries.section('pages').locale(craft.locale).level(1) %}
<nav>
    <ul>
        {% for page in pages %}
            <li>{{ page.getLink() }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</nav>
```

There are many different ways to create language links, several of which are [described in this thread...](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/44/45)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately this isn`t working, too, when having a multi-environment config. Navigating to an english page, e.g. http://craft.dev/en/page-1, results in links like http://craft.dev/page-2, without the locale in it.  This behavior seems to depend on my config.

Comment: Sounds like you may have hit a snag in [Step 4: Define your site URLs...](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/localization-guide#step-4-define-your-site-uRLs)