# Language link not working for me

Tags: config, language

I've tried the LanguageLink and the last solution described here: [How can I build a language switcher?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/44/how-can-i-build-a-language-switcher/6611#6611) but it never returns any URI. I'm not using translated slugs.

As setup I've used: http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/localization-guide. The language dropdown is part of top.html which I've included in each page

Things I have checked:

- /config/general.php and that looks fine
- index.php in public_html/stagingtest/ (for english) and public_html/stagingtest/es/ and public_html/stagingtest/nl/ and appears to be ok
- when I go to www.example.com/stagingtest/es/report/ its loading fine. craft.locale appears to be ok, but the language uri's are still blank. I can see siteUrl is displaying the correct uri.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have accidentally add "return array.." two times in my config/general.php file. I removed one and its working fine now.